# Unable to update MapCenter in windows phone 8.1 WinRT App with MyMap.Mapcenter

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

Please help me.

the scenario is there are two pages in my app one is map page(MainPage.xaml) and other is map location search page(LocationSearch.xaml) when i run the app on my phone map center location is update as i want but when i go to second page and searching the location and back to the map page with the new location co-ordinates the map center location is not updating

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

    // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
    // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
    // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
    // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
    // this event is handled for you.

    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {

        BinMapPins.AppData.Resultclass myobject = e.Parameter as BinMapPins.AppData.Resultclass;

        BasicGeoposition locPos = new BasicGeoposition();


        if (myobject != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("lat " + myobject.address);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("lat " + myobject.lat);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("lang " + myobject.lang);
            locPos.Latitude = myobject.lat;
            locPos.Longitude = myobject.lang;
            areaInfo.Text = myobject.address;
            MyMap.Children.Clear();
            Geopoint gopoints = new Geopoint(locPos);
            MyMap.Center = gopoints;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("geo point val: " + gopoints.Position.Latitude);
            MyMap.ZoomLevel = 16;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        callMap();

    }
}
```

Comment: How you are handling the Page Navigation? Are you Caching the main page? Some more details please.

Comment: no i am not handling the page navigation

Comment: i just use  Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), myobject);
               for sending data to first page

Comment: Ok the page u created is basic page or blank page. Or the project is blank or basic?

Comment: I created a blank project and then added a blank page

Comment: Try creating basic page instead of blank page because the basic page handles the navigation things by itself.